# MongoDB replica-set upgrade Arbiter fail. 3.6 - 4.0 - 4.2

Tags: mongodb, version, upgrade, replicaset

Can't find much related information about this error but maybe someone here can explain it to me.

Hosting version 3.6 Mongodb replica set with master/slave and arbiter setup.   Im trying to upgrade my cluster to 4.2 version.  Quite straightforward process. First upgrade your nodes one by one to 4.0 and then 4.2. Set compabilty version to 4.0 and later 4.2 if everything goes as expected.

This process works well until I´m trying to upgrade arbiter to 4.2. Before that I verified arbiter compabilty version which was 4.0 But right after I install 4.2 packages to Arbiter it goes down and I get this error from logs, - "2021-01-08T15:02:17.282+0200 F  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: BadValue: Invalid value for version, found 3.6, expected '4.2' or '4.0'. "  But as I mentioned I verified its featureCompatibilityVersion before I upgraded to 4.2.

Current workaround to get arbiter working is to take it off from  replica set and set and manually re set featureCompatibilityVersion and later adding it back to replica set.

Is it expected behaviour or Im doing stmh wrong in my process ?

Comment: Add full logs to question. When you run 4.0 arbiter again do you see 3.6 or 4.0 fcv?

Comment: It does not look like a "proper" solution but my suggestion is this: The arbiter does not store any data; drop it entirely (i.e. stop and remove folder `dbPath`) restart and add it to the replica set. Maybe you have to remove it before hand. It is not worth to spend hours in trouble shooting.

Comment: Upgrade documentation states *Ensure that no replica set member is in ROLLBACK or RECOVERING state.* - Perhaps you were too fast.

Comment: Most certainly  I wasnt too fast or smth like this. I tried to fix this and different approaches    for 3 hours but still same bug.  

If some of you have time guys I challenge  you to set up 2node + arb 3.6 cluster and try to upgrade it to 4.2.  If someone manage to do it properly then beers on me :D

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem, and eventually narrowed down the cause to be the arbiter having data stored on it before trying to upgrade. In our case, the arbiter had users added before it become an arbiter (as they wouldn't have been able to be added afterwards). The users get stored in the arbiter's data directory, and it appears this not a valid state for a cluster, causing issues on upgrade.

Fix was to remove the arbiter's data directory before upgrading.